# How to, in one line, add a variable in a for-loop?

Tags: java, loops, variables

Here is a snippet of Java code that has really baffled me over the past couple of days. The goal is to insert only one line of code in the given place such that the number printed after "Given: " is 5050. I do not want to write multiple lines or change any of the existing lines of code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        // In one line, write code such that 5050 is printed out.
    }
    System.out.println("Given: " + x);
    System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
}
```

I know that 5050 is the sum of the first 100 natural numbers, and this is evident in the for loop, which sets x to each of these consecutive numbers during each occurrence. If I could find a way to add the values of x to each other, that could have been a solution. The problem is that I want the value of x to be 5050 when I exit the loop, so that the "Given: " line prints out 5050 as the value of x.

I also know that I can use another variable to store the temporary value of the sum, i.e. `y += x;`, however, this would be impossible since I wouldn't be able to declare y multiple times within the loop, and the value of x needs to be 5050, not y. Also, if I try `x += x`, the result will definitely not be 5050 because of the way the variable is being changed by both the for loop execution and the addition operation.

So, is there actually a solution to this problem?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile as `x` is out of scope when the `System.out.println` is called.

Comment: So, does `x = 5050;` satisfy your criteria?

Comment: This won't ever happen. There is absolutely no way how this one line can introduce an `x` in the scope of the `main` method. @KyrSt No. Nothing ever can satisfy these criteria. Unless you are allowed to close the parentheses in this "one line", of course.

Comment: Actually, x=5049. But you have to move the declaration of x to be outside the loop. @KyrSt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make two changes. First, you **must** make `x` visible outside the `for` loop. Otherwise there is literally **no** way to access it after the loop. Then, all you have to do is set `x` to the desired value (minus one), which will terminate the loop after the value is incremented and tested. Like,

```
int x;
for (x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
    x = 5050 - 1;
}
System.out.println("Given: " + x);
System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
```

Outputs

```
Given: 5050
Expected: 5050
```

The **only *other*** legal way to write it is like

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
} int x = 5050; {
}
System.out.println("Given: " + x);
System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
```

which isn't "really" kosher in my opinion. Note that we terminate the loop, add a new `x` variable and an empty block in that one line.

Answer (score 3):

You can close the parentheses of the `for`-loop in this line, and introduce a new variable `x` in the same line:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        }; String x = "5050"; {
    }
    System.out.println("Given: " + x);
    System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
}
```

Greetings from Bobby Tables...

---

**EDIT**:

As @ElliottFrish has pointed out, the following trick with `System.exit(0)` after first loop iteration does not work, because there is still no `x` in scope:

```
// Doesn't work.
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
       System.out.println("Given: 5050"); System.out.println("Expected: 5050"); System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Given: " + x);
    System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
}
```

However, we can force this `System.exit(0);`-solution to compile by moving the given `System.out.prinln`s into an unrelated method:

```
class BobbyForloops {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
            System.out.println("Given: 5050\nExpected: 5050"); System.exit(0); }} public static void unrelated(int x) {{
        }
        System.out.println("Given: " + x);
        System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
    }
}
```

Now it again compiles and outputs what was asked. But it's just a variation of the first solution.

**Edit:** Thanks @Dukeling for proposing a much shorter solution that uses `System.exit(0);`. @Dukeling's solution is actually even shorter, because it uses a `break` instead of `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Second solution doesn't compile. No `x` after the loop. But adding a `static String x = null;` (or `x` equal anything) outside `main` could fix that!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ah, right! So close! Why is java compiled and not interpreted line by line^^ xD

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ...and I'm pretty sure that there is no simple way to inject something into the `javac` itself so that it outputs the two desired lines, and then crashes without any message, without finishing the compilation of the code... The `javac` is probably stable enough to be not easily exploitable in this way.

Comment: @Dukeling if it was my question, and if your comment was an answer, I would definitely upvote you, awesome! xD Should I update my answer with that?

Comment: @Dukeling ok, added (without `\r` though, can't test it on windows anyway). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The comment within the code doesn't say **where** the one line has to be placed, although your post suggested it needs to replace the comment.  Taking the comment literally though, this works:

```
public class X {
    private static final String x = "5050";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
            // In one line, write code such that 5050 is printed out.
        }
        System.out.println("Given: " + x);
        System.out.println("Expected: 5050");
    }

}
```